# Triangular gallery thumbnail hover and on-click html website

Tags: jquery, html, geometry, gallery, thumbnails

[image]

Hi guys.

I am coding an online portfolio for college. I have design this thumbnail gallery layout (as shown in image) and now have two problems.

1) I would like to have a hover effect over each triangle that changes the saturation of the image inside the triangle to show it can be selected. (without dead space obviously as I know triangles are tricky when it comes to on-click and hover commands)

2) And I am not sure where to start in terms of a lightbox zoom effect once a thumbnail has been clicked on because I need to include 3 images in each project with a short description. Suggestions?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without reinventing the wheel, you can use this plugin [diamond plugin](http://mqchen.github.io/jquery.diamonds.js/).

If you want it you can see its code to respond to your questions.